How to connect to Azure VM Windows Admin Center from Azure DevOps without enabling PSRemoting in VM
I want to connect to Azure VM Windows Admin Center from Azure DevOps without enabling PSRemoting/WinRM in VM for some automation.
VM doesn't configured RDP, SSH or any other. Need to connect only through WAC.
I tried with PSremoting but due to some policy PSRemoting should be in disable mode. So now I want some alternatives that can connect to VM Windows Admin Center

Please clarify "connect to Azure VM Windows Admin Center from Azure DevOps " in details. Windows Admin Center is used in the Azure portal to manage the Windows operating system inside an Azure VM. It's a browser-based management tool. You can't connect to it. See the detailed info about WAC from What is Windows Admin Center?.

You can make Use of Windows Admin Center Gateway (Web-based UI)
Windows Admin Center (WAC) operates as a web-based interface. If your VM already has WAC installed, you can connect to it through its web interface using Azure DevOps pipelines. Just make sure that:
Public or Private IP: The VM has either a public IP or you can access the WAC through a private network connection (VPN or Azure Bastion).
Firewall rules: Ensure the network security groups (NSGs) on the VM allow HTTP/HTTPS traffic on port 443 (WAC default port).
Self-signed certificate: WAC often uses a self-signed certificate; you may need to trust this certificate in Azure DevOps or bypass certificate validation.
